# ASP.NET MVC Add chebox filtering

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have a table of orders,

filtering, sorting and records per page is done via server side.

How can i make the filtering of the status with the checkbox (see attached screenshot) work?

When changing entries number or searching in searchbox or sorting the action that retrieve the data is triggered (GetList()) , i want to trigger it when check\Uncheck  one of the checkbox  status.

[image]

My Action :

```
public ActionResult GetList()
        {
            //Server Side parameters
            int start = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["start"].FirstOrDefault());
            int length = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["length"].FirstOrDefault());
            string searchValue = Request.Form["search[value]"].FirstOrDefault();
            string sortColumnName = Request.Form["columns["+Request.Form["order[0][column]"]+"][name]"].FirstOrDefault();
            string sortDirection = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"].FirstOrDefault();
            List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>();
                orderList = _unitOfWork.Order.GetAll().ToList();
            int totalRows = orderList.Count;
            foreach (Order order in orderList)
            {
                order.StringDate = order.UsDate.Day + "/" + order.UsDate.Month + "/" + order.UsDate.Year;
            }
//
 //filtering done here
//
            int totalRowsAfterFiltering = orderList.Count;
//
//Sorting done here
//
            //orderList = orderList.OrderBy(x => x.Id //sortColumnName + " " + sortDirection).ToList<Order>();
            orderList = orderList.Skip(start).Take(length).ToList<Order>();
            foreach (Order order in orderList)
            {
                order.AllowComplaint = allowComplaint(order.Id.ToString());
            }
            return Json(new { data = orderList, draw = Request.Form["draw"], recordsTotal = totalRows ,
                        recordsFiltered = totalRowsAfterFiltering});
        }
```

Javascript\Ajax call the Action :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tblData').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "OrderAdmin/GetList",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "name": "Id" },
                { "data": "orderStatus", "name": "OrderStatus" },
                { "data": "productName", "name": "ProductName" },
                { "data": "stringDate", "name": "StringDate" },
                { "data": "userNameToShow", "name": "UserNameToShow" },
                { "data": "storeName", "name": "StoreName" },
                {
                    "data": "quantity", "name": "Quantity", "render": function (data) {
                        if (data > 1)
                            return `<div class="text-center" style="font-weight:bold;background-color:darkseagreen"><label >${data}</label></div>`
                        else
                            return `<div class="text-center"><label>${data}</label></div>`
                    }
                },
                { "data": "cost", "name": "Cost" },
                {
                    "data": "fullAddress", "name": "FullAddress", "render": function (data) {
                        return `<textarea readonly>${data}</textarea>`
                    },
                    "width": "20%"
                    },
                { "data": "trackingNumber", "name": "TrackingNumber", "width": "200px"},
                {
                    "data": {
                        "orderStatus": "orderStatus",
                        "id": "id",
                        "allowComplaint": "allowComplaint"
                    },
                    "render": function (data) {
                        if (data.orderStatus == 'Accepted') {
                            return `
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <a href="/Admin/OrderAdmin/UpdateOrder/${data.id}" class="btn btn-success text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                         `}
                        else if (data.orderStatus == 'Done' && data.allowComplaint) {
                            return `
                                          <div class="text-center">
                                            <a href="/Admin/Complaints/AddComplaint/${data.id}" class="btn btn-info text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                            <i class="fas fa-ticket-alt"></i>
                                            </a>
                                          </div>
                                        `
                        }
                        else { return `<div></div>` }
                    }, "width": "5%"
                }
            ],
            "serverSide": "true",
            "order": [0, "desc"],
            "processing": "true"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Anyone? 
Still stuck :)

Comment: Can you share a smallest and reproducible project  on the github?